# How can I get the positions of elements regardless of what they are from a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to print elements in order of diagonals on a matrix. However, there must be a common term in the position of the element.

For example, [image: this image.] The diagonal and everything below it is grayed out because it is a symmetric matrix and unneeded. The red chain skips position 13 and goes to position 24, then 14, and then back to 13. This is because there was no common term in the positions of 02 and 13.

I believe I can code this, but I don't know how to actually use the POSITION of an element as something that I can compare to another position.

Comment: Your rules to produce chain 1 and chain 2 wasn't really clear to me, there is another way or example that you could give?